# HTML DIV with absolute position: how to make it 100% wide and zoom-safe?

Tags: css, html, width, absolute

I have a following HTML/CSS (simplified):

```
<body>        
<style>
        body
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #090909;
            text-align: center; 
        }

        #content
        {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #header
        {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            background-color: green;
        }

        #over-div {
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            height: 20px;   
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px; 
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
            -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
            -moz-opacity: 0.5;
            opacity: 0.5;
       }
</style>
<div id="over-div">aa</div> 
<div id="header">
        header
</div>
<div id="content">
        content here
</div>
</body>
```

The idea is to have over-div to cover the upper part of the page completely (but do not keep it fixed there, so it is not visible when user scrolls down the page).

If you zoom-in extremely (Ctrl+ wheel) till the horizontal scrollbar appears, you can see that after scrolling completely to the right, the over-div does not cover the header completely to the right side of window.

I hoped that width:100% would mean "always use 100% width of the body", but it seems it is not true for absolute positioned divs.

Tested browsers: Firefox 3.5, Chrome, IE8 (with and without compatibility mode).

Is there any way to get that div cover 100% width of page?

Comment: is there going to be actual text in the `over-div` or do you just care about the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add this to the #over-div styling:

```
min-width:500px;
```

That ensures that #over-div will be at least as wide as your #header and #content divs

Comment: just in case it matters IE6 does not support this.

Comment: Thanks, min-width:500px; together with width: 100%; did the trick. IE8 in compatibility view also shows it fine, so I hope IE7 will support it too. I do not care about IE6 for this project.